# In ListBox cannot add Items after ItemSource is set to null

Tags: wpf, silverlight, listbox, wpf-controls, itemssource

I have assigned ItemsSource property of first ListBox 'ListBox1' as the ItemsSource of another ListBox namely 'ListBox2' . If I set ListBox2's ItemsSource as null, then I am unable to add any Items further to ListBox1's ItemsSource.

Below is the xaml snippet,

```
         <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Margin="0 25 0 0"
                 x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Coll,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Margin="0 25 0 0"
                 x:Name="ListBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource,ElementName=ListBox1,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In Code behind, I set the ItemSource of ListBox2 as null on button click like below,

```
        ListBox2.SetCurrentValue(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, null);
```

Once this is done, I tried to add Items to ListBox1's "Coll" collection, but throws NRE that "Coll" is null.

Any suggestions plz.

Regards,
Dinesh Kumar P

Comment: Why not just set the ItemsSource of ListBox2 to Coll?

Answer (score 0):

The two-way binding on `ListBox2.ItemsSource` sets `ListBox1.ItemsSource` to `null` when `ListBox2.ItemsSource` is set to `null`. Subsequently, the two-way binding on `ListBox1.ItemsSource` also sets `Coll` to `null`.

Don't make the `ItemsSource` bindings two-way. It is not necessary, and collection changes will still be notified.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Coll}" ... >
    ...
</ListBox>
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=ListBox1}" ... >
    ...
</ListBox>
```

It's not really clear what you are going to achieve, but it may be better to also bind `ListBox2.ItemsSource` directly to the `Coll` property.

Comment: Hi Clemens, without twoway binding, collection changes get notified. But my problem is after setting ListBox2.ItemsSource to null, Collection "Coll" changes are notified only in ListBox1 and not notified in ListBox2, when I add an item in "Coll" collection.

Comment: Of course not *after* you set it to null. What exactly is your intention when you set ListBox2.ItemsSource to null?